# How to get 2 fixed and 1 dynamic column in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm dealing with this issue for 2 days. I tried "display: flex" and a lot of combination but no one can get me the result that I want.

I need the CSS to get this layout (check image).

I could have 2 possible differents HTMLs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Left Button</div>
    <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Left Button</div>
    <div class="item">Center button</div>
    <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
```

What shuold I set in the CSS to get this layout:
[image: Layout]

Check that in the image you have both examples. The first one for the first HTML, and the second for the second HTML.

Basically, I want:

- All the items should have the same width. Always. Always.
- ALWAYS the items should have close to 33% of the container width.
- In case that we have 3 items, the middle item should have 10px of margin left and right. BUT, remember the first point! All the items should have THE SAME WIDTH. That is a important point because you can't take 20px of the width to use as margin, because you'll have 20px less in the middle item.

One of the things that I tried is:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.items {
    flex: 1 0 0;
}

.items:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

But it's totally wrong.

I also tried this thing, but, again, wrong:

```
.container {
    display: block;
}

.items {
    width: 33%;
}

.items:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Ok. I'll add what I'm trying.

Comment: I'm assuming that the 33% is just to indicate they elements are all the same size since 20px won't always be 1%?

Comment: You can set the width that you want. The 33% is just a way to say: "All the width with items". Edge to edge. Full of items.

Comment: I'm using % just because it should be resposive. The items should take the 100% of the with... It's kind of: "I have a 3 buttons in a responsive design, and sometimes I have 2, and I want the same width for them, always"

Comment: Exactly. But, another options could be good. If you have 2 different css that can work with one example and another with the other example, it could be helpful

Comment: Please, check the image, and read the text.

Comment: Are you saying that you were betting your luck for two days, but you didn't think about reading MDN docs or W3C specs?

Comment: 2 days, only 1 hour per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flexbox can do that.

```
.item {
  background: #f00;
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  background: #f00;
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Left Button</div>
  <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Left Button</div>
  <div class="item">Center button</div>
  <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
```

Apparently, the middle margin is important so we can fall back on `max-width` and `calc` (thanks to Pangloss).

```
.item {
  background: #f00;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: calc((100% - 20px)/3);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  background: #f00;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: calc((100% - 20px)/3);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.multi .item:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Left Button</div>
  <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
<div class="container multi">
  <div class="item">Left Button</div>
  <div class="item">Center button</div>
  <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about the margin left and right in the center button? That is the most important issue

Comment: Paulie, please, check the 3 points that I wrote. 1. items should have the same width, and in case that we have a 3º item in the middle, it should have 10px and 10px. Please, check the 3 points that I wrote.

Comment: That is a good option, but, "always" (in both layouts) the items should have the same width. Check that your 2 "Left item" have different widths

Comment: Edited...now with max-width and calc.

Comment: Very good improvement! But, what about removing the "multi" class? :D The last important thing!

Comment: Hey! I guess if you JUST remove the "multi" class, it's still working. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Just remove the CSS for .multi and the class in the HTML and it'll be working well! perfect! thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting the CSS table layout, you could probably get the same thing with flexbox too. You might need a set of CSS for each markup.

```css
body {
    background: gold;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    margin: 0 -10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
.item {
    display: table-cell;
    background: aqua;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
    /* visibility: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Left Button</div>
    <div class="item">Center button</div>
    <div class="item">RIght button</div>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbcg10pw/)**

Comment: Please, add the "2 items" html so we can see the snippet and check if the buttons have ALWAYS the same width

Comment: Yeah, I already put it there, like Paulie did, just uncomment that line. Due to the table layout limit, it needs to keep the middle item in the markup but hidden.

Comment: That is a trick! You are hidding the 2º items, but, if I only have 2 items, you will be hidding the "Right item"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something like that?

```css
.test{
  display:table;
  width:100%
}

.test > div{
    width: calc(100% - 66.66% - 20px);
    margin-left: 10px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}

.test > div:first-child,
.test > div:last-child {
  background-color:#C1C1C1;
  width:33.33%;
  margin: 0;
}

.test > div:last-child{
  float:right
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  
</div>

<div class='test'>
  <div>1</div> 
  <div>3</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: What about the margin left and right in the center button? That is the most important issue. Please, check the 3 points that I wrote in the question, where I say: "Basically, I want:"

Comment: Buttons have different width. 215 and 195px.

Comment: Your answers is very good because I don't need to add something more in the HTML. Is one of the best answers, but, check that the buttons should have the same width always (in both layouts)